# AJAX não respeita forEach

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho um banco com duas colunas, a saber: Atividade e status.
Tenho uma table na minha página com todas as Atividades, e desejo saber o status de cada uma delas.
Selecionei todas as tr's e uso um ajax dentro de um forEach, porém o AJAX não vê cada uma das tr's, ele vê apenas uma.

Além disso, ele retorna algumas vezes que o PHP não carregou, porém está sempre passando os mesmos dados pelo POST, como pode ora carregar e ora não, se não muda nada nos parametros?

Não sei se é relevante, mas antes desse ajax, eu estou rodando outro, no mesmo evento "change" de um select.

código javascript

```js
function verificaVinculados() {
  formulario_vincular = document.querySelector("#formulario_vincular");
  formulario_vincular.funcao_vincular.value = "verificar";

  atividades = document.querySelectorAll(".atividade");

  atividades.forEach(function(atividade) {
    formulario_vincular.atividade_vincular.value = atividade.firstChild.id;

    xhr_atividadeVinc = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr_atividadeVinc.open("POST", "banco/banco-vision/pagina-cadastrar-empresas/vincular-atividades.php");

    console.log(formulario_vincular.atividade_vincular.value); //Aqui ele sempre mostra cada uma delas.
    xhr_atividadeVinc.addEventListener("load", function() {
      console.log(formulario_vincular.atividade_vincular.value); //Aqui ele sempre mostra a mesma atividade
      if (xhr_atividadeVinc.status == 200) {
        console.log("carregou com sucesso");
      } else {
        console.log("Falha ao carregar o php");
      }
    });
    xhr_atividadeVinc.send(new FormData(formulario_vincular));

  });

}

html
```

```html
<form id="formulario_vincular">
  <label>Empresa: </label>
  <!--Aqui vai o nome da empresa, via click javascript-->
  <label id="empresa_vincular"></label>
  <input type="hidden" name="cod_emp_vincular">
  <input type="hidden" name="tributacao_vincular">
  <input type="hidden" name="atividade_vincular">
  <!--Confere tal atividade-->
  <input type="hidden" name="funcao_vincular">
  <!--Função de controle sobre o php-->
  <label>Departamento: </label>
  <select name="dep_vincular">
    <?php
            while($linha_departamentos1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_departamentos1))
            {
           ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $linha_departamentos1[" DEPARTAMENTO "];?>">
        <?php echo $linha_departamentos1["DEPARTAMENTO"];?>
      </option>

      <?php
            }
           ?>

  </select>
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <td>Atividade</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabela_vincularAtividades">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

código que uso pra preencher a tabela com as atividades

```js
formulario_vincular.dep_vincular.addEventListener("change", function() {
  formulario_vincular.funcao_vincular.value = "listar";
  xhr_atividadePorDep = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr_atividadePorDep.open("POST", "banco/banco-vision/pagina-cadastrar-empresas/vincular-atividades.php");
  xhr_atividadePorDep.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (xhr_atividadePorDep.status == 200) {
      tabela_vincular = document.querySelector("#tabela_vincularAtividades");
      tabela_vincular.textContent = "";
      atividades_disponiveis_vincular = JSON.parse(xhr_atividadePorDep.responseText);
      atividades_disponiveis_vincular.forEach(function(atividade) {
        montaTabelaVincular(atividade);
      });

    } else {
      console.log("Falha ao buscar php");
    }

  });

  xhr_atividadePorDep.send(new FormData(formulario_vincular));

  setTimeout(verificaVinculados(), 9000);

});


function montaTabelaVincular(atividade) {
  tabela_vincular = document.querySelector("#tabela_vincularAtividades");
  atividadeTr = document.createElement('tr');
  atividadeTr.classList.add("atividade");

  tipo_atividadeTd = document.createElement('td');
  tipo_atividadeTd.textContent = atividade.ATIVIDADE;
  tipo_atividadeTd.id = atividade.ATIVIDADE;

  statusTd = document.createElement('td');
  statusTd.textContent = "pendente";

  tabela_vincular.appendChild(atividadeTr);
  atividadeTr.appendChild(tipo_atividadeTd);
  atividadeTr.appendChild(statusTd);
}
```

Comment: Acho que isso deveria ser feito de forma sincronizada. Vc está fazendo um forEach enviando várias requisições ao mesmo tempo e com a mesma variável. O certo seria fazer uma requisição e só fazer outra após o retorno da anterior, até terminar tudo.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer isso? Já tentei colocando readyState == 4, já coloquei com setTimeOut, tentei de várias formas e sempre dá a mesma coisa. Tem algo diferente do ajax? Tentei, inclusive colocando session_write_close() no php, pois li que poderia ser um bloqueio no php, mas também sem sucesso.

Comment: Veja se ficou entendível

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma função recursiva que faz uma requisição após a outra quando a anterior foi processada.

Crie uma variável de controle com valor `0`. Após uma requisição ter sido processada, incremente `+1` a essa variável. Enquanto o valor dela for menor que o número de elementos em `atividades` a função será novamente chamada até chegar no último elemento.

```
var conta = 0; // variável de controle
function verificaVinculados(){
   formulario_vincular = document.querySelector("#formulario_vincular");
   formulario_vincular.funcao_vincular.value = "verificar";

   atividades = document.querySelectorAll(".atividade");

   var atividades_len = atividades.length; // conta o número de elementos

   formulario_vincular.atividade_vincular.value = atividades[conta].firstChild.id;

   xhr_atividadeVinc = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr_atividadeVinc.open("POST", "banco/banco-vision/pagina-cadastrar-empresas/vincular-atividades.php");

   console.log(formulario_vincular.atividade_vincular.value); //Aqui ele sempre mostra cada uma delas.
   xhr_atividadeVinc.addEventListener("load", function(){
      console.log(formulario_vincular.atividade_vincular.value); //Aqui ele sempre mostra a mesma atividade
      if(xhr_atividadeVinc.status == 200){
         console.log("carregou com sucesso");    
      }else{
         console.log("Falha ao carregar o php");
      }

      conta++; // incrementa a variável
      if(conta < atividades_len){
         verificaVinculados(); // chama novamente a função
      }else{
         conta = 0; // ao terminar tudo, zera a variável novamente
      }
   });
   xhr_atividadeVinc.send(new FormData(formulario_vincular));
}
```